# Generic Event Generator and Handler from User Supplied Types?

Tags: c#, events, c#-4.0, generics, types

I'm trying to allow the user to supply custom data and manage the data with custom types. The user's algorithm will get time synchronized events pushed into the event handlers they define.

I'm not sure if this is possible but here's the "proof of concept" code I'd like to build. It doesn't detect T in the for loop: "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found"

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Algorithm algo = new Algorithm();
        Dictionary<Type, string[]> userDataSources = new Dictionary<Type, string[]>();

        // "User" adding custom type and data source for algorithm to consume
        userDataSources.Add(typeof(Weather), new string[] { "temperature data1", "temperature data2" });

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            foreach (Type T in userDataSources.Keys)
            {
                string line = userDataSources[typeof(T)][i]; //Iterate over CSV data..
                var userObj = new T(line);
                algo.OnData < typeof(T) > (userObj);
            }
        }
    }

    //User's algorithm pattern.
    interface IAlgorithm<TData> where TData : class 
    {
        void OnData<TData>(TData data);
    }

    //User's algorithm.
    class Algorithm : IAlgorithm<Weather> {
        //Handle Custom User Data
        public void OnData<Weather>(Weather data) 
        {   
            Console.WriteLine(data.date.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    //Example "user" custom type.
    public class Weather {
        public DateTime date = new DateTime();
        public double temperature = 0;

        public Weather(string line) {
            Console.WriteLine("Initializing weather object with: " + line);
            date = DateTime.Now;
            temperature = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
 string line = userDataSources[t][i]; //Iterate over CSV data..
 var userObj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
 algo.OnData<t>(userObj);
```

Same error but now its on OnData so it can't call the generic event, because it doesn't recognise T as a generic type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @O.R Mapper and @galenus :: using a combination of both your answers this works elegantly without needing much reflection. With the added assumption there's a base data class which contains datetime -- a common index across all timeseries data.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAlgorithm algo = new Algorithm();
        Dictionary<Type, string[]> userDataSources = new Dictionary<Type, string[]>();
        userDataSources.Add(typeof(Weather), new string[] { "temperature data1", "temperature data2" });

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            foreach (Type t in userDataSources.Keys)
            {
                string line = userDataSources[t][i]; //Iterate over CSV data..

                var userObj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

                UserData castObj = (UserData)userObj;
                castObj.Constuctor(line);

                algo.OnData(castObj);
            }
        }
    }

    interface IAlgorithm
    {
        void OnData(object data);
    }

    abstract class BaseAlgorithm<TData> : IAlgorithm where TData : class 
    {
        public void OnData(object data) 
        {
            //perform type checks here, if necessary
            OnData(data as TData);
        }
        protected abstract void OnData(TData data);
    }

    //User's algorithm.
    class Algorithm : BaseAlgorithm<Weather>
    {
        //Handle Custom User Data
        protected override void OnData(Weather data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.date.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public abstract class UserData {
        public DateTime date;
        public UserData() { }
        public abstract void Constuctor(string line);
    }

    public class Weather : UserData 
    {
        public DateTime date = new DateTime();
        public double temperature = 0;

        public Weather() { }

        public override void Constuctor(string line) {
            Console.WriteLine("Initializing weather object with: " + line);
            date = DateTime.Now;
            temperature = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeof(x)` will return the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) instance denoted by the type name `x`.

In your case, you already have a `Type` instance; your variable `T` is of type `Type`. So, you should not need to use `typeof`:

```
string line = userDataSources[T][i];
```

---

As a recommendation about style, there is no reason for using a capital `T` for the name of your local variable; it is a normal local variable just like `i`, so just call it `t`. `T` looks like a generic parameter, which it is not.

---

The next two lines won't be that easy, though:

```
var userObj = new T(line);
algo.OnData < typeof(T) > (userObj);
```

As `T` isn't known at compile-time, you cannot make any calls like that. You will have to use reflection to perform those calls - first, use the [`Activator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class to create an instance of whichever type `T` currently references (with `userObj` being typed to [`System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) at compile-time).

Subsequently, retrieve the [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) instance of your `algo`'s `OnData` method and invoke [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) to get the generic version with `T` inserted. You can then call [one of the `Invoke` overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke.aspx) to actually execute the `OnData<T>` method.

Comment: Cheers @O. R. Mapper -- I found that one myself as well. It still doesn't work by the next line though. Will attach new lines in edit

Comment: Another PS: All user data must have time stamp, so a base class "UserData" could also make sense which includes the date variable across different user data types.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of things you do wrong with generics:

1. Algorithm interface and its implementation cannot look like you've defined them. Once you specify the generic parameter of type, you don't have specify it again in the method. So this will work:

   ```
   //User's algorithm pattern.
   interface IAlgorithm<TData> where TData : class
   {
       void OnData(TData data);
   }

   //User's algorithm.
   class Algorithm : IAlgorithm<Weather>
   {
       //Handle Custom User Data
       public void OnData(Weather data)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(data.date.ToString());
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
   ```

   And the usage in this case would be:

   ```
   var userObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, line);
   algo.OnData((Weather)userObj);
   ```
2. You cannot use the key information as you would generic argument. Generic argument is compile-time, *Type* instance - runtime. There are ways, through reflection, but they are ugly and inefficient. So, no *new T(line)*. Moreover, even if you had the right generic argument here, you could only create it using default constructor and only in case you had [*new()* constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) on the argument.
3. No *algo.OnData<t>(userObj)* either, see the previous bullet.

I would propose you the following:

```
    //User's algorithm pattern.
    interface IAlgorithm
    {
        void OnData(object data);
    }

    abstract class BaseAlgorithm<TData> : IAlgorithm where TData : class
    {
        public void OnData(object data)
        {
            //perform type checks here, if necessary
            OnData(data as TData);
        }

        protected abstract void OnData(TData data);
    }

    //User's algorithm.
    class Algorithm : BaseAlgorithm<Weather>
    {
        //Handle Custom User Data
        protected override void OnData(Weather data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.date.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @galenus -- I'll tidy it, but the generic event generation is the harder part-- how do you generate the "ugly and inefficient" events? Is there a clean way since the Event-Generator won't know the types at compile time.

Comment: See the edit of the first bullet. Regarding the ugly and inefficient - this is in case you have to dynamically construct generic type or generic method, you are to use [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) or [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) (as O.R.Mapper suggested), accordingly. This type of code is dirty and suffers from performance degradation. When you can - avoid it and find another solution.